# why the $ sign in awk don´t pass correctly in my bash?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I'm new to awk and bash. I'm trying to do some formating for several different files. But I don't get what I want. The $ sign don't pass correctly, I tried with $, \, "", the -v chr="$" command. But since I know little I really don't understand why is not working:

THXS!!

```
cat<< END2> par.tem  
cat<< END> temp  
awk '{  
if ($5 == "1")  
 val = 202  
else if ($5 == "4")  
 val = 300  
else  
 val =$5 ;  
if (NR > 8 && $6 < 9999)  
printf "%14.3f%14.3f%12.3f%12d%12.5f\n", $1, $2, $3, val, $6     
}' sbrt_202_300_xyz.out > sbrt_au_202_300_xyz.asc  
END  
bash temp  
END2

sed -e "s/RX1/202/g" -e "s/RX2/300/g" -e "s/NUM1/1/g" \
    -e "s/NUM2/4/g" par.tem > run-temp
bash run-temp
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use variable passing to get shell variables into AWK variables.

```
awk -v "awkvar=$shellvar" '{print $awkvar}' file
```

to print the awkvar-th field, for example.

Similarly:

```
awk -v "awkvar=$1" '{print $awkvar}' file
```

Comment: @John: Those are field specifiers which do need dollar signs, see "to print the awkvar-th field, for example" in my answer.